# How to check the performance of a django application?

Tags: python, django, profiling

I have created a django app. Now i want to test the application's performance with some 5000 data. Is there any method to do it ? Is there any method to randomly enter this data into db and run the application ? I believe there should be some method rather than typing 5000 data manually into db. The database i use is mysql. I am quite new to Python and Django, so please help me to solve this . Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[pycheesecake.org](http://pycheesecake.org/wiki/PythonTestingToolsTaxonomy) provides a good source of testing tools for python.

You might also want to checkout [django-autofixture](https://github.com/gregmuellegger/django-autofixture), a nice tool for inserting randomly generated data into the database, and [django-mockups](https://github.com/sorl/django-mockups), which is a fork from django-autofixture.

Here is a sample usage of django-autofixture:

```
django-admin.py loadtestdata [options] app.Model:# [app.Model:# ...]
```

You just supply the app name, model and the number of objects that you want to create.

Answer (score 4):

Check out [django-dilla](https://github.com/aerosol/django-dilla).  It helps you to spam your database with random data

There's no real good documentation, but you'll need to install it and add it to your `INSTALLED_APPS`, then run `python manage.py run_dilla` from the command line.

To view the options run `python manage.py run_dilla --help` which let you specify counts and the apps to "spam".  Check out the [command source](https://github.com/aerosol/django-dilla/blob/master/dilla/management/commands/run_dilla.py) for implementation details.

Comment: thanks for the reply sdolan.. I checked out djang-dilla, but couldnt find any document for how to use it. Since i am a newbie in Django, i am little confused how to use it. Is there any document explaining the process of it?